# Size and Colour in Julia Scatter Plot

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I want create a scatter plot. I have point size and colour in additional variables (vectors).

```
x = Float64.(1:10)
y = Float64.(1:10)
c = Float64.(1:10)
s = Float64.(1:10)

scatter(x,y)
```

I've been googling very long now and could not find the right answer. What I am looking for is this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you part of the way there:

```
x = 1.0:10.0
y = 1.0:10.0
c = 1.0:10.0
s = 1.0:10.0

theme(:ggplot2)
scatter(x, y; zcolor=c, markersize=s, color=:oslo)
```

I didn't have time to try to figure out the legends.

[image]

There are a nearly unlimited number of colorschemes, have a look here if this one isn't exactly right: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/colorschemes/

Comment: Thanks a lot. `zcolor` and `markersize` are not very intuitive to me: why the "z" in `zcolor`?
Oh, just to be sure, because I cannot check it right now: `theme(:ggplot2)` doesn't have anything to do with the answer, right?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Plots.jl, I just found this by looking at the docs. I guess zcolor relates the colors as a third (z) dimension of the data, in addition to x and y. Markersize, on the other hand is quite intuitive, imo, and similar to e.g. Matlab. The `theme` was just to get some visual similarity to the OP plot, gray background/white gridlines.